# How to use argument of a function as name of variable?

Tags: string, r, function, variables, arguments

I have the feeling that this is trivial, and I apologize for asking such easy questions, but I would appreciate some help with the following problem: I have a function which requires two arguments:

```
myfun <- function(fm, name){
  ... 
}
```

The data frame to be used I can get via `dat <- eval(fm$call$data)` inside the function. Inside `dat`, there is a variable with a name identical to the second argument, i.e. there is a variable `dat$name` (note that the second argument of the function does not include the reference to the dataframe, i.e. name does not equal `dat$name` but just `name`) and I would like to use that variable.

Q: How can I do that?

Concrete example: The following serves as an example:

```
  air <- data(airquality)
  fm <- lm(Ozone ~ Solar.R, data=airquality)
  myfun <- function(fm, name){
  df <- eval(fm$call$data)
  name[1:5]
  }

  myfun(fm, Temp)
```

The purpose of this function is to show the first five elements of the variable `name` in the dataframe that has been used for fitting `fm`. However, `name` is not recognized as the variable in the corresponding data frame. Neither wrapping it with `with(df, ...)`, `df$name` or equivalent solutions does the trick. How do I get it to work?

**Edit:**
I have played around a bit further but it is still not working. This is what I thought should work after I was inspired by some of the comments:

```
  myfun <- function(fm, name){
  df <- as.character(fm$call$data)
  varname <- deparse(substitute(name))
  d1 <- paste(df, "$", sep="")
  d2 <- paste(d1, varname, sep="")
  get(d2)[1:5]
  }

  myfun(fm, Temp)
```

This produces a character string called `airquality$Temp`, but I get the following error:
      `Error in get(d2): object 'airquality$Temp' not found.`
I was hoping that by constructing a string which gives me the name of the variable including the data frame I could access it using `get`, but something still does not work... :(

Comment: I'm a little confused, but you may just want `[[` as in `dat[[name]]`... but you might also be looking for `get`.  I'm particularly confused by why you would need to `eval` your data...

Comment: This question is certainly confusing and could benefit from a strong re-write

Comment: @Justin: `str(fm$call$data)` shows that this yields a "symbol" as output, whereas `str(eval(fm$call$data)` shows the relevant data frame. Frankly, I copied this from an answer to another question here. I would appreciate any advice on how to make this more elegant.

Comment: it looks like the data you are working with is likey the output of a model, is that correct?   You can acccess its components individually, without much `call` trickery

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: I edited my post and added a concrete example. I hope that this makes my question clearer.

Comment: Posting the data makes everything so much easier

Comment: If you only care about the columns used in the call, there's `fm$model[1:5,]`, too.

Comment: The above is unfortunately only a toy example. My "real" application is much more complicated. ;) Anyway, my current problem is that I do not manage to make the argument of the function recognized as a variable name, for which this example is sufficient, I hope.

Comment: `get` will only work with an object, not part of an object as you're trying to do with `get(data$var)`. You can do it in steps, however, `get(data)[[var]]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example,

```
air <- data(airquality)
fm <- lm(Ozone ~ Solar.R, data=airquality)

myfun <- function(fm, name){
  dn <- fm$call[['data']]
  varname <- deparse(substitute(name))
  get(as.character(dn),envir=.GlobalEnv)[varname]
}

myfun(fm, Temp)
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot! I did not even think of local and global environments and was just trying to coerce my string into some other format. But now that I think about it, it is indeed an easy and quite obvious solution. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3):

you want to use `get`, however there is no guarantee that the data.frame will be there.

```
> head(get(as.character(fm$call$data)), 5)
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
```

However, all that `as.character(fm$call$data))` is giving you is the **name** of the `data.frame` object. 
If you already have that piece of information, which you can pass to the function, it would be much simpler to use

```
 head( get(Name), 5)
```

*note that head is giving you the first five **rows**, not just the first five elements*

Comment: Just to make the problem more apparent: the reason why I want to get the data frame from the fitted model is that I frequently use different subsets of the data. The subset has to be specified in `lm()` and I would like to avoid specifying it in my function again when I change it. Typing `lm(y~x, data=df[some lenghty condition]` and additionally `myfun(fm, df[some lenghty condition]$variablename)`appears tedious and inefficient. Just imagine changing your subset of the data 50 times. Including this into my function would really help me save time.

Comment: great, well there you have it.  Although, you might want to look into programatic methods to accomplish your task ;)